# got stuck in recursion return value

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have written a small recursive function to find the level of menuItem.
Here is the function:

```
const getSelectedMenuItemLevel = (menuItems, path, level = 0) => menuItems.forEach((menuItem) => {
  console.log(menuItem.path, path, menuItem.path === path, level);
  if (menuItem.path === path) {
    return level;
  }
  return getSelectedMenuItemLevel(menuItem.children, path, level + 1);
});
```

This is how I call it:

```
console.log(getSelectedMenuItemLevel(menuItems, 'two/three'));
```

Here is the menuItems Array:

```
[
  {
    path: 'one',
    name: 'One',
    children: [
      { path: 'one/one', name: 'One/One', children: [] },
      { path: 'one/two', name: 'One/Two', children: [] },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: 'two',
    name: 'Two',
    children: [
      { path: 'two/one', name: 'Two/One', children: [] },
      { path: 'two/two', name: 'Two/Two', children: [] },
      { path: 'two/three', name: 'Two/Three', children: [] },
    ],
  },
{
    path: 'three',
    name: 'Three',
    children: [],
  }
]
```

This recursive function always returns me `undefined`. I expect it to return `level`

Comment: [*forEach*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) always returns *undefined*, you can't return any other value from it.

Comment: @RobG then what should i use instead? `map`?

Comment: Probably [*reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), but *filter* might work too.

Comment: @RobG I will try it. I think `filter` won't work as filter will return me an `item` instead of `return value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a variable in the function and store it by checking the iteration for a found level with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), bedcause this method uses a short circuit if a valid level is found.

Basically you need to extend the wanted return values to `undefined` or to a numerical value.

```js
const getSelectedMenuItemLevel = (menuItems, path, level = 0) => {
    let value;
    menuItems.some((menuItem) => {
        if (menuItem.path === path) {
            value = level;
            return true;
        }
        const temp = getSelectedMenuItemLevel(menuItem.children, path, level + 1);
        if (temp) {
            value = temp;
            return true;
        }
      return false;
    });
    return value;
};


var menuItems = [
  {
    path: 'one',
    name: 'One',
    children: [
      { path: 'one/one', name: 'One/One', children: [] },
      { path: 'one/two', name: 'One/Two', children: [] },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: 'two',
    name: 'Two',
    children: [
      { path: 'two/one', name: 'Two/One', children: [] },
      { path: 'two/two', name: 'Two/Two', children: [] },
      { path: 'two/three', name: 'Two/Three', children: [] },
    ],
  },
{
    path: 'three',
    name: 'Three',
    children: [],
  }
];

console.log(getSelectedMenuItemLevel(menuItems, 'two/three'));
```

Comment: Tried it on my end. It works fine, except a warning. You should have `return false` at the end of `some`. I will edit your answer and add it for future reference. Big thanks for taking time to solve this problem.

Comment: the function returns `undefined` by default, which if interpreted as a falsy value by `some`.